# Deconstruct and convert in React

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, destructuring

A react component receives props and I'm deconstructing it like this:

```
const { ram, core } = this.props;
```

But I want to divide the `ram` value by `1024`, of course I could go with:

```
let { ram, core } = this.props;
ram /= 1024;
```

Can I do it in one line and use const too?

Comment: one possibility `const ram = this.props.ram/1024, { core } = this.props;` ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it this way:

```
const { ram, core } = ( ({ ram, core }) => ({ ram: ram/1024, core }) )(this.props);
```

```js
const props = { ram: 2048, core: 7 };


const { ram, core } = ( ({ ram, core }) => ({ ram: ram/1024, core }) )(props);

console.log(ram);
```